Using Vertex Agent Builder to build a chatbot to answer questions about my website. I have indexed the website as Data Store, but still get no answer
So I have been trying for almost a week now to create a chatbot using Google Vertex Ai Builder (ex "Search & Conversation" feature of Vertex).
I have created a Data Store linking to my website, so that the bot would read my website and respond to any questions from the users with information from the website. The process of creating, indexing and linking the data store to the app have all been successful.
Whenever I use the "Test Agent" function of Dialogflow, however, the bot gives me either no answer at all or "I don't understand, please rephrase the question".
Any idea of what might be going on and how to fix it?
Thanks!
